# Communicating between angular4 siblings components by holding components reference in a service

Tags: angular

I'm looking to communicate between two siblings angular4 components.

I've read this doc: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction but I was thinking about a solution that a service holds a component (which needs to be access) reference.

A `service` holds reference to `Second` component. `First` component uses the `service` to access `Second` component reference and executes any method in it.

This solution allows to execute methods synchronically.

Here's a working plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/NkPB09wuk0F4xG7BFIcM/

My question is regarding this code design.

Isn't it actually a circular dependency which is not recommended ? Or this might be a reasonable solution to communication between siblings components ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be arranging communication between components in a loosely-coupled fashion. But your code has tight coupling. Your service knows that there are exactly two components. What if you need to introduce a third component that needs the same service? Based on your plunker, you'll need to modify the service.

The service shouldn't know who's using its data. Create an instance of the Subject inside the server and let the first component invoke next() on this Subject. A second component can subscribe to this subject. If the third component will need this data, the third component can subscribe to the same Subject and there is no need to update the code of the service. I recorded a video that shows how to arrange inter-component communication this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYNEH_k0e_4

Comment: I'm familier with that Subject pattern. The thing is that next is async. What if I need to wait that second component would end what it needs to do? I wouĺd need to have another Subject and invoke next from second component. It's kinda messy.

Comment: "What if you need to introduce a third component that needs the same service? Based on your plunker, you'll need to modify the service." - No. Third service just needs to get a reference from the global injector and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Yakov in that this does not seem like a good practice.

But instead of a Subject or BehaviorSubject, I'd recommend just a simple service. I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

I updated your plunker to illustrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/RyHJgzZLBUlxj15jLGAt?p=preview

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalCommunicator {
  private message: string;
}
```

Comment: your solution only concerns in cases of sharing data. what if I want to trigger actions?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: suppose second component wants to trigger some first component methods (synchronically)

Comment: As Yakov said, sibling components communicating directly cause a tight coupling. Normally you would instead set it up that they both communicate with a service OR they both notify the parent that then notifies the other children.

Comment: I updated your plunker to illustrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/RyHJgzZLBUlxj15jLGAt?p=preview

Comment: I don't think tight-coupling is the issue here because I can easily make First component to implement IFirst interface and let the service recognize only IFirst.